# Need solution for my error while implementing clahe of opencv in javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I've tried to use clahe of opencv 3.0.0 in javadoc. I used this code

```
public class CLAHE {
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{


      // Loading the OpenCV core library
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

      // Reading the Image from the file and storing it in to a Matrix object
      Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("grayscaleiskemik.jpeg");

      // Creating an empty matrix to store the result
      Mat dst = new Mat();

      Imgproc.createCLAHE(40, Size(8, 8)); //line 26

      // Writing the image
      Imgcodecs.imwrite("clahe.jpeg", dst);
  }
}
```

but I got an error in line 26. It says

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just came from C++ background. You should use the `new` operator while creating new objects. Use the following code:

```
Imgproc.createCLAHE(40, new Size(8, 8));
```

Comment: still get some error sir, it says "Size cannot be resolved to a  type"

Comment: by the way, can u give me a link of how to implement clahe function from opencv in javadoc?

Comment: Did you import `org.opencv.core.Size`?

Comment: yes, and now more error. but the line to read the image get a warning and it saying "this code in un used.